# Modern way to deal with deprecations on iOS/macOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, deprecation-warning

How to suppress deprecation warning within availability macro? I know availability is a great way to check for new APIs but I am struggling how to suppress deprecation warnings. What alternatives do I have other than those mentioned below? (1.pragma 2.performSelector)

```
MyModel *model;
if (@available(macOS 10.13, *)) {
    NSError *error;
    model = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectOfClass:[MyModel class] fromData:metadata error:&error];
    if (error) {
        [[NSAlert alertWithError:error] runModal];
    }
} else {

#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated"

    model = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:metadata];

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
}
```

Alternatively use to suppress warning

```
if ([NSKeyedUnarchiver respondsToSelector:@selector(unarchiveObjectWithData:)]) {
    model = [NSKeyedUnarchiver performSelector:@selector(unarchiveObjectWithData:) withObject:metadata];
}
```

Comment: Do you want to mark your methods as deprecated?

Comment: Please re-read.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. You should not get any deprecation warning in your `else` block if the deprecation is OS version specific.

Comment: Just not use deprecated methods. Alternatively you can suppress deprecation warning by lowering deployment target to version where they wasn't deprecated.

Comment: I think your's deployment target is 10.14 now. So you don't even need `@available(macOS 10.13, *)` check.

Comment: _how to suppress deprecation warnings_ You should not "suppress" them. You should not _want_ to "suppress" them. You should _respond_ to them.

Comment: You don't suppress them.  You pay attention to them and then update the code to use the more modern alternative to them.

Comment: I am checking it using availability macros. Should not suppress them? -> why do they pop up if I already check using availability for new API. The problem is the I used APIs older than deployment target an seems availability macro doesn't like it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will only get a deprecation warning if you are using an API that was deprecated at or earlier than your target's Deployment Target.

`NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData` is deprecated as of macOS 10.14. You will only get a deprecation warning if your target's Deployment Target is macOS 10.14 or later. But the code you posted implies you wish to support macOS 10.12 or earlier.

`NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectOfClass:fromData:error:` was added in macOS 10.13.

If you really only want a Deployment Target of macOS 10.13 or later then you don't need the `if (@available(macOS 10.13, *))` or the `else`. Just use the new API and be done.

The code in your question (minus the pragmas) should only be used if you want to support macOS 10.12 or earlier. Then your target's Deployment Target needs to be set to macOS 10.12 or earlier. And in this case you don't need the pragmas and you won't get any deprecation warnings.

Comment: Thanks, for clarification. I use deployment target 10.12 and switch it to 10.14 under mojave.